# How to configure the Emmet abbreviation for doc for a customized html boilerplate?

Tags: html, boilerplate, emmet

I'm using Emmet with Sublime Text 2 and am trying to customize the abbreviation for `doc` in a particular way. Here is [Emmet's documentation](http://docs.emmet.io/).

Emmet's `doc` can be initiated by expanding the `!` character when beginning a new html5 page from scratch. The following is Emmet's default output when expanding the `!` character:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to configure `doc` so that it's output is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<header>

</header>

<footer>

</footer>

<script src="js/"></script>
```

My `snippets.json` file attempts the desired output like so:

```
{
    "html": {
        "abbreviations": {
            "doc": "(html+meta[charset=UTF-8]+title{${1:Document}}+meta:vp+link:css)>header+footer+script:src"
        }//abbreviations
    }//html
}//root
```

But the output is awful, like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"></html>
<meta charset="UTF-8" lang="en">
<title lang="en">Document</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" lang="en">
<header lang="en"></header>
<footer lang="en"></footer>
<script src="" lang="en"></script>
```

My questions are:

1. how to remove `</html>` altogether?
2. how to remove all of the `lang="en"` attributes after the `<html>` tag?
3. how to change the default style path to `css/style.css`?
4. how to keep the white space as show in my desired outcome above?

Answer (score 4):

To get the basic HTML5 template

Ensure you have Emmet packages/ plug-ins installed into your text editor (e.g. Atom or Brackets)

You need to know what your 'expands abbreviation' key(s) are:

- in Atom: TAB
- in Brackets: command+alt+enter (Mac) or CTRL+alt+enter (Win & Linux)

1) Ensure your text editor is set to HTML. Editing in say hbs moustache won't work, so you may wish to use a scratchpad html file to create the template on first

2) First type **`!`** then 'expands abbreviation' key(s)

3) If Viewport is not created

- insert 'viewport'with  **meta:vp** then 'expands abbreviation' key(s)
- delete 'user-scalable=no' and minimum-scale maximum-scale to look like [Googles](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/ConfigureViewport?hl=en) `<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

4) To insert style and other links with **link:css**  then 'expands abbreviation' key(s)

Its a bit 'simple simon' but it works for me.

Note: you can always change your then 'expands abbreviation' key(s) settings in preferences in your Emmet plug-in

Comment: The command `html:5` has an alias `!` in Emmet. If you simply type an exclamation point and expand it, you get the same template as `html:5`.

Answer (score 1):

1. You shouldn’t remove `</html>` tag, you need to write correct abbreviation. Something like this: `html>(head>meta[charset=UTF-8]+title{${1:Document}})+body>header+footer+script[src="js/"]`
2. See above
3. Override `link:css` abbreviation or simply use `link[href="..."]`
4. Use `{$nl}`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it, but have you tried prefixing the sections with escape codes, such as a tab `\t` to fix the formatting of the output?

Comment: Hi @knice. what I've been doing lately is just hardcoding the templates I want instead of using Emmet's dynamic syntax which I never got working like I wanted. Also, my desired html boilerplate template has changed from above.

What I've been working with lately looks like this:

https://gist.github.com/brianzelip/af721d3c5e9a03ff417b